# Magento2 Form Post posting empty

Tags: php

I am wondering what would cause a form post to always post empty? However when I take the same html form outside of magento and put into a plain php page the form post works? Here is my form code

```
 <form class="form subscribe" action="./newsletter_signup_success" method="post">
        <div class="field newsletter">

            <div class="control">
                <input name="eaddr" type="email" id="footer_newsletter" placeholder="Sign Up & Save 15%"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php echo __('Subscribe') ?>" type="submit">
                <span><?php echo __('Subscribe') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Then the  index.php file which is outside magento 2.1 in a folder called newsletter_signup_success I have this code

```
<?php
   $emailaddr = $_POST['eaddr'];
    print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS);
   echo " $emailaddr";
?>
```